# What is the issue with this Google Sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried so many combination, the Google sheet sometimes return the right result,, sometimes it doesn't. ( I am 100% sure using the same formula). I tried to run this formula on a brand new worksheet, but still not working.

`=arrayformula(if(ISBLANK(A2),"",if(and(M2="PLANNING",N2="BUILD AHEAD"),"N",if(and(ISBLANK(J2),G2+7>today()),"Y",if(K2>G2+7,"Y","N")))))`

The Google Sheet says IF statements only allow up to 3 arguments, but I think it shouldn't be.

I searched this forum, and someone mentioned that we shouldn't use "AND" or "OR" in arrayformula. I replaced "AND" with "+", but still got an error result.

Does anyone know what's the issue with my formula?

Dummy Data:
Cell: A2 = `Michael`, G2 = `2022-01-01`,  J2 = `2022-02-02`,   K2 = `2022-03-03`.

I am trying to get a result of "Y" or "N" in Cell L2.

The expect result should be:

- If G2+7 > today's date, I will get "Y" in cell L2.
- If K2 < G2 + 7, I will get "N" in cell L2.

Comment: It just make sense to share a spreadsheet with sample (dummy) data so people here can see what you're trying to do and then come up with a solution. Please do mention as well the expected result.

Comment: Cell: F2, I2, J2 all contains a date

Comment: google sheet will give you a wrong result only when you give it wrong input, in most cases.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details like the spreadsheets regional formal, the cell data type (not all values that look as dates are dates) and sample data for cases that doesn't work and for cases that work.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
 IF((M2:M="PLANNING")*(N2:N="BUILD AHEAD"), "N",
 IF(ISBLANK(J2:J)*(G2:G+7>TODAY()), "Y", 
 IF(K2:K>G2:G+7, "Y", "N")))))
```

AND & OR are not supported under ARRAYFORMULA